# How to change text color in marquee tag on every refresh

Tags: javascript, html

Appreciate help in resolving the below issues.....

With every refresh, I wanted to change the text color in marquee tag by calling javascript function......
I am getting color code like #18EEC5 ......but when calling script function from marquee tag nothing is happening......

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getRandomColor() {
var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
var color = '#';
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
}
return color;
}   
</script>
</head>
<body>  
<script> 
$col=getRandomColor();
document.write(getRandomColor()); 
</script>
<marquee style="color: 'document.write(getRandomColor())'; font-size: 20pt; font-weight: bold">
Text Color Changes
</marquee>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.write()` doesn't do what you're expecting here. I'm sure you can see the problem when loading the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
</script>

<style>
#marquee {
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<marquee id="marquee">Text Color Changes</marquee>

<script>

$marquee = document.getElementById('marquee');
$marquee.style.color = getRandomColor();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue got resolved...  Thanks, Igor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to rerun code every time it loads

```
 <body onload="getRandomColor()">
```